# How to perform CRUD with different textarea using JS and PHP | QA comment system

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I googled for it but did not understand . I am working on a QA forum like stackoverflow . I can write and handle PHP codes but the JS is challange for me .
As you know that , every question on forum contain an comment box where user can comment.
I have worked for single textarea . It's working cool but when I create second textarea for second answer it doesn't work. Everytime only first textarea works .
Index.php

```
<style>
body{width:40%;}
.message-box{margin-bottom:20px;border-top:#F0F0F0 2px solid;background:#FAF8F8;padding:10px;}
.btnEditAction{background-color:#2FC332;border:0;padding:2px 10px;color:#FFF;}
.btnDeleteAction{background-color:#D60202;border:0;padding:2px 10px;color:#FFF;margin-bottom:15px;}
#btnAddAction{background-color:#09F;border:0;padding:5px 10px;color:#FFF;}
</style>
<?php
require_once("config.php");

?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function showEditBox(editobj,id) {
    $('#frmAdd').hide();
    $(editobj).prop('disabled','true');
    var currentMessage = $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html();
    var editMarkUp = '<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_'+id+'">'+currentMessage+'</textarea><button name="ok" onClick="callCrudAction(\'edit\','+id+')">Save</button><button name="cancel" onClick="cancelEdit(\''+currentMessage+'\','+id+')">Cancel</button>';
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(editMarkUp);
}
function cancelEdit(message,id) {
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(message);
    $('#frmAdd').show();
}
function callCrudAction(action,id) {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    var queryString;
    switch(action) {
        case "add":
        //get closest comment list box
      var selector = $(id).closest(".comment-list-box")
      //get text area and post id values
      var txtmessage = selector.find(".txtmessage").val()
      var postid = selector.find(".postid").val()
      console.log(txtmessage + " --" + postid)
            queryString = 'action=' + action+ '&txtmessage=' + txtmessage+'&postid='+ postid;
            
            
        break;
        case "edit":
            queryString = 'action='+action+'&message_id='+ id + '&txtmessage='+ $("#txtmessage_"+id).val();
        break;
        case "delete":
            queryString = 'action='+action+'&message_id='+ id;
        break;
    }    
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "crud_action.php",
    data:queryString,
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        switch(action) {
            case "add":
                $(".comment-list-box").append(data);
                 //selector.append(data);
      //empty the textareas 
   

            break;
            case "edit":
                $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(data);
                $('#frmAdd').show();
                $("#message_"+id+" .btnEditAction").prop('disabled','');    
            break;
            case "delete":
                $('#message_'+id).fadeOut();
            break;
        }
        $("#txtmessage").val('');
            $("#postid").val('');
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
function commentdh() {
  $("#cbd").show();
   $("#cbd1").show();
}
</script>
<?php $res = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comment where postid=119"); ?> 
<div class="form_style">

<div class="comment-list-box">
<div id="frmAdd"><textarea name="txtmessage" class="txtmessage" cols="80" rows="2"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" value="119" name="postid" class="postid">
<p><button id="btnAddAction" name="submit" onClick="callCrudAction('add',this)">Add</button></p>
</div>
<img src="LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" />
</div>
<?php
if(!empty($res)) {
while($comments=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
?>
<div class="message-box" id="message_<?php echo $comments['id'];?>">
<div class="message-content"><?php echo $comments['message']; ?></div>
<div>
<button class="btnEditAction" name="edit" onClick="showEditBox(this,<?php echo $comments['id']; ?>)">Edit</button>
<button class="btnDeleteAction" name="delete" onClick="callCrudAction('delete',<?php echo $comments['id']; ?>)">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
} ?>
</div>

<?php $res = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comment where postid=120"); ?>

<div class="form_style">
<div class="comment-list-box">
<div id="frmAdd"><textarea name="txtmessage" class="txtmessage" cols="80" rows="2"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" value="120" name="postid" class="postid">
<p><button class="btnAddAction" name="submit" onClick="callCrudAction('add',this)">Add</button></p>
</div>
<img src="LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" />
</div>
<?php
if(!empty($res)) {
while($comments=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
?>
<div class="message-box" id="message_<?php echo $comments['id'];?>">
<div class="message-content"><?php echo $comments['message']; ?></div>
<div>
<button class="btnEditAction" name="edit" onClick="showEditBox(this,<?php echo $comments['id']; ?>)">Edit</button>
<button class="btnDeleteAction" name="delete" onClick="callCrudAction('delete',<?php echo $comments['id']; ?>)">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
} ?>
</div>



<!--    This may be 3,4,5, answers------ etc from database with comment box -->
```

crud_action.php

```
     <?php
require_once("config.php");
$action = $_POST["action"];
if(!empty($action)) {
    switch($action) {
        case "add":  
            if(strlen($_POST["txtmessage"])<12)  { 
            echo "<font color='red'>12 characters atleast </font>";
            } 
            else {
                echo $_POST['postid']; 
            $query = "INSERT INTO comment(message,postid) VALUES('".$_POST["txtmessage"]."','".$_POST["postid"]."')";
            $run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
              $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
            if($insert_id){
                  echo '<div class="message-box"  id="message_' . $insert_id . '">
                        <div>
                        <button class="btnEditAction" name="edit" onClick="showEditBox(this,' . $insert_id . ')">Edit</button>
<button class="btnDeleteAction" name="delete" onClick="callCrudAction(\'delete\',' . $insert_id . ')">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-content">' . $_POST["txtmessage"] . '</div></div>';
            }
            }
            break;
        case "edit":
            $query = "UPDATE comment set message = '".$_POST["txtmessage"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["message_id"];
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            if($result){
                  echo $_POST["txtmessage"];
            }
            break;          
        case "delete": 
            if(!empty($_POST["message_id"])) {
                $query = "DELETE FROM comment WHERE id=".$_POST["message_id"];
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
            }
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

Everytime the first textarea works .

[image]

Value from second textarea
[image]
In the image above , you can see the first comment box is working but if i enter in second box , it doesn't work .
How can i solve it for CRUD operation for different answers.
Like stackoverflow , user can comment on any answer using textarea and every textarea works .
I want use JS function one time for all texareas . How to do that all texarea work using same function for CRUD operation like stackoverfloe comment box below answers.

I am attaching my database table here -

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `postid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my database table for comment with postid and comment id autoincrement...
Also i am providing more easy way .
My connecton file -
config.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbName = 'test';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$conn= mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your warning . Now  i have changed my code to prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `id` to get value of `textarea` and `postid` input boxes .But , mutliple elements cannot have same ids so instead of that use `class`. Now, whenever `add` button is clicked you can pass `this` as well in your parameter . Here , `this` will refer to current element which is clicked so using this you can use `find()` and `closest()` to get input values which is inside `comment-list-box` where button has been clicked and passed same to backend page .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function callCrudAction(action, id) {
  $("#loaderIcon").show();
  var queryString;
  switch (action) {
    case "add":
      //get closest comment list box
      var selector = $(id).closest(".comment-list-box")
      //get text area and post id values
      var txtmessage = selector.find(".txtmessage").val()
      var postid = selector.find(".postid").val()
      console.log(txtmessage + " --" + postid)
      queryString = 'action=' + action + '&txtmessage=' + txtmessage + '&postid=' + postid
      break;
      //other codes
  }
  /*jQuery.ajax({
    url: "crud_action.php",
    data: queryString,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {*/
  switch (action) {
    case "add":
      //selector.append(data);
      selector.append("<div>okok</div>"); //just for demos..
      //empty the textareas 
      selector.find(".txtmessage").val('');
      break;
      //other codes
  }
  $("#loaderIcon").hide();
  /* },
    error: function() {}
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_style">
  <!--use class--->
  <div class="comment-list-box">
    <!--use class for text area and input--->
    <div id="frmAdd"><textarea name="txtmessage" class="txtmessage" cols="80" rows="2"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" value="119" name="postid" class="postid">
      <!--pass `this` as well --->
      <p><button class="btnAddAction" name="submit" onClick="callCrudAction('add',this)">Add</button></p>
    </div>
    <img src="LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" />
  </div>
  <div class="message-box" id="message_1">
    <div class="message-content">something..</div>
    <div>
      <button class="btnEditAction" name="edit" onClick="showEditBox(this,1)">Edit</button>
      <button class="btnDeleteAction" name="delete" onClick="callCrudAction('delete',1)">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--    This is second comment box below second answer -->
<?php $postid=120; ?>
<div class="form_style">
  <div class="comment-list-box">
    <div id="frmAdd"><textarea name="txtmessage" class="txtmessage" cols="80" rows="2"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" value="120" name="postid" class="postid">
      <p><button class="btnAddAction" name="submit" onClick="callCrudAction('add',this)">Add</button></p>
    </div>
    <img src="LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" />
  </div>
  <div class="message-box" id="message_11">
    <div class="message-content">Nice..</div>
    <div>
      <button class="btnEditAction" name="edit" onClick="showEditBox(this,11)">Edit</button>
      <button class="btnDeleteAction" name="delete" onClick="callCrudAction('delete',11)">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One more thing only first texarea value is working .  I have changed my code accroding to your code but did not solve.

Comment: can you show your updated code ? you can see in above demo code ..console printing correct value .

Comment: why you are using `id="comment-list-box"` ? id here it should be `class="comment-list-box"` . Also ,  don't empty your post id input i.e:`$("#postid").val('');` <-- remove this line

Comment: why you have `queryString = 'action=' + action+ '&txtmessage=' + $(".txtmessage").val()+'&postid='+ $(".postid").val();` it should be `queryString = 'action=' + action+ '&txtmessage=' + txtmessage+'&postid='+ postid;` .please make changes according to my code .

Comment: The code is working now but there is small issue . If i enter value from first or second text box it displays below both textarea but after referesh page it's working . I want the firxt texarea comment display below the only first textarea and if i add comment using socond textarea , it should display below the second textarea before refereshing . I have updated code . You can check above with screenshot .

Comment: change `$(".comment-list-box").append(data);` to `selector.append(data);` .

Comment: Thank you dear for this help . One more think on the stackoverflow when i click add a comment the textarea comes (show) and after submit comment the comment box value removes and textarea closes every time .   Is there any function to do that for all textarea not for one like stackoveflow ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226726/discussion-between-vishal-rana-and-swati).

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on("click",".btnEditAction",function(){
var CommentId=$(this).closest(".Comment_Edit").find("message-box").text();
var Comment=$(this).closest(".Comment_Edit").find("message-content").text();
//Then Call Ajax Function
})
```